# SQL query by getting current time

Tags: java, mysql, sql, time

My project is about to get current classes for a school, I created the database with table CLASSES that contains START_TIME (ex: 16:00) and END_TIME (ex:18:00) columns. and i have the variable 'hour' that will be take the current time from system.

My question is: what is the best way to query the database to get the current classes , for example ( SELECT * FROM CLASSES WHERE START_TIME='hour' );

that worked for me if the current time is the same as the start time, but what if the current time is between the START_TIME and END_TIME ? for example class is from (16:00 to 19:00) and the current time is 15:00 ? how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what exactly solved my problem to show only result i want ( not before or after results that BETWEEN operator did) :

```
SELECT * FROM CLASSES WHERE 'currentTime' >= START_TIME AND 'currentTime' < END_TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `between` like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CLASSES 
WHERE currentTime BETWEEN START_TIME AND END_TIME;
```

Another option would be to use the `>=` and `<=` operators.

Comment: the second option is what exactly i need ,it displayed only the (current classes) as I want:

SELECT * 
FROM CLASSES 
WHERE 'currentTime' >= START_TIME AND 'currentTime' < END_TIME

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT * FROM CLASSES WHERE 'hour' BETWEEN START_TIME AND END_TIME
```

But it depends on how start and end times are stored in DB. As numeric values (e.g 16, 18)? And what about hour value? Is it numeric value as well? 
In all 3 values are numeric, the query above will work. 
If they are stored in some different format, the answer should be adjusted.

Comment: BETWEEN operator works but it gives me sometimes classes that are after or before the current class because BETWEEN includes both START_TIME and END_TIME, >= and < operators solved the exact problem.